# If trapped by a web lurker, can I only use acrobatics to Escape?

Tags: monsters, pathfinder-2e

The [Web Lurker](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=407) has the ability "Web Trap". It says (emphasis mine):

> A creature hit by the web lurker’s web attack is immobilized and stuck to the nearest surface until it succeeds at DC 20 **Acrobatics** check to Escape.

This seems to be a reference to the [Escape](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=79) action, which includes the following:

> Attempt a check using your unarmed attack modifier against the DC of the effect.

> You can attempt an **Acrobatics** or **Athletics** check instead of using your attack modifier if you choose

As the Web Lurker does explicitly specify Acrobatics, does that mean that you can only use Acrobatics to Escape from that Web Trap?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## That is probably a typo

While RAW, yes, you are limited to Acrobatics to escape, this is almost certainly a typo. There are several monsters with the Web Trap ability as a ranged attack:

The [Drider](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=207):

> **Web Trap** A creature hit by a drider’s web attack is immobilized and stuck to the nearest surface (Escape DC 21).

The [Dream Spider](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=813) (and, naturally, many other spiders):

> **Web Trap** A creature hit by the dream spider's web attack is immobilized and stuck to the nearest surface until it Escapes (DC 16).

There is nothing in a [Weblurker's](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=407) description or stat block that would indicate that there webs are immune to destruction or have any other properties different from a normal web. Additionally, the Weblurker is from the first Bestiary, which was developed simultaneous with the final ruleset; it's possible that when the Weblurker was written (pre-PF2's publishing) Acrobatics was going to be the only way to Escape.

The first Bestiary contains other currently unaddressed problems like this: for example, the counteract level on the [Clay Golem's](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=240) cursed wound makes it equivalent in difficulty to dispel as a 10th level spell... which is quite wrong for a 10th level creature. So I think it is wise to approach stat blocks from so early in PF2e's history with a mindset that "common sense should override RAW", which is what leads to me say the Weblurker is probably a typo.